# Google marker doesn't display

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-studio, marker

in the following code does not display the marker.This code I have made with previews android studio editions and there was no problem with tracking but now there is.I want to make a google map with tracking tab and for this reason I think can't use activity but only fragment.Anyone knows how it can be done?

```
public class Tab2Map extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    MapView mMapView;
    View mView;

    public Tab2Map() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab2, container, false);
        return mView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view,Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onViewCreated(view,savedInstanceState);

        mMapView=(MapView) mView.findViewById(R.id.map);
        if(mMapView != null){
            mMapView.onCreate(null);
            mMapView.onResume();
            mMapView.getMapAsync(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        MapsInitializer.initialize(getContext());
        mGoogleMap = googleMap;
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                LatLng latlng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
                mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latlng).title("Current Location").snippet(latlng.toString()));
                CameraPosition position=CameraPosition.builder().target(latlng).zoom(16).bearing(0).build();
                mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(position));
            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            }
        };

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5, 15, locationListener);
    }
}
```

fragment_tab2.xml

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Tab2Map">

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/map"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: show `layout.fragment_tab2`

Comment: @serg3z I added the xml to my question.Thanks